# How to put Constraints on Positioned widget in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, widget, constraints

How can I put a constraint to PositionedWidget? Instead of having a fix height, I would like to give minHeight to it.

```
Stack(
    children: [
      Positioned(
        width: 300,
        height: 300,
        child: Container(
         child: SomeWidget(),
        ),
      )
    ],
  );
```

I tried putting a constrained on Container and doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your positioned widget with constrained box .

```
ConstrainedBox(
constraints: BoxConstraints(minHeight: 5),
        
child: Positioned(child: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.add), 
onPressed: () {  },),),
        
      ),
```

Comment: If I wrap the Positioned widget, flutter says that Position parent must be a stack.